# remove leading and trailing whitespace mips?

Tags: mips

so I figured out this program that basically codes a number pattern and the numbers have to be tabbed in between each other, so for example:

1  1   1

but the last "1" also has a tab and i need to remove that. this is what my code looks like for tabbing: i use this before the end of my for loop, so it can incrementing how many ever times. i don't really know where to start for creating a conditional that doesn't print the last number with a tab

```
li $v0, 11      #this is for tabbing the numbers 
        li $a0, 9   
        syscall
```

Comment: while current character is tab, copy entire buffer forward from tab to current location.  Slow, but would work.

Comment: Michael, your explanation is kind of confusing, can you reword it?

Comment: Scan each character in buffer.  When you find a Tab, copy from bufferPos +1 to tab location at bufferPos + 0 the entire buffer -1.  Decrease recorded buffer size by 1.  Then continue through buffer.  Again not at all efficient, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough code to give a full answer, but there are several ways to omit printing the last tab:

If you know you are processing the last item you can jump over the print tab code, e.g. suppose you are in a while-loop where you loop while `$t0` is different than `$t1`, then you can write:

```
while_loop:
   # .... do something
   beq $t0, $t1, skip
   # your code to print tab
   li $v0, 11      #this is for tabbing the numbers 
   li $a0, 9   
   syscall
skip:
   # ... something else
   bne $t0, $t1 while_loop  % this is the condition to keep in the loop
```

---

if the printing of the tab is the last thing you were doing in the loop, then you can simplify a bit:

```
while_loop:
   # .... do something
   beq $t0, $t1, while_loop
   # your code to print tab
   li $v0, 11      #this is for tabbing the numbers 
   li $a0, 9   
   syscall
   b  while_loop
```

---

Another approach is to print the tab at the beginning of the loop, save for the first iteration. Useful if you are iterating over some values on a register and know some initial value wont be repeated. In this example I will just use a supposedly spare register:

```
li $t7, 0  # $t7 will only have 0 on the first iteration of the loop
while_loop:
  beq $t7, $zero, skip
  # your code to print tab
  li $v0, 11      #this is for tabbing the numbers 
  li $a0, 9   
  syscall
skip:
  li $t7, 1
% your remaining code here, which at some point goes to the while_loop
```